# Populating values inside tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have below requirement to do in XSLT.

```
<SOAPBODY>
<Response Id = "" Name="" input="" >
<Status></Status>
</Response>
</SOAPBODY>
```

How do I populate the fields inside Response Tag i.e., Id, Name, Input? 
Those values come from XPath. But when I try to keep them in Tag, it's not successful as XSL is not allowing me to keep an xsl:copy-of selct inside that tag.

What I am trying is

```
<Response 
Id = "<xsl:value-of select=$Id"
Name="<xsl:value-of select=$Name" 
input=""<xsl:value-of select=$input" >
>
<Status></Status>
</Response>
</SOAPBODY>
```

Response should be closed only after Status Tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Attribute Value Templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) here.

```
<Response 
      Id = "{$Id}"
      Name="{$Name}" 
      input="{$input}">
   <Status></Status>
</Response>
```

The curly braces indicate it is an expression to be evaluated, rather than output literally, and so `{$id}`, for example will be replace by whatever the value of the $id variable is.